# Event @change is fire but cant get it in Vue Component Verte

Tags: vue-component

can't catch the changed event

my template code:

```
<template>
      <verte @change="changeColor(1)"></verte>
</template>

<script>
import Verte from 'verte';

export default {
  components: { verte }
  methods: {
   changeColor(id) {
    console.log(id)
   },
}
</script>
```

[image]

in vue inspector event @change starts..

tried changing this line
from `import Verte from 'verte';`
to `import VertePicker from 'verte';`
...

but as a result, only the input event fires, but I just can’t catch the event on changed

maybe something else is needed to correctly trigger the event? and could this be a component bug?

Answer (score 0):

Verte is not supporting change event.
You can call changeColor as below.

```
<template>
      <verte v-model="colorVal"></verte>
</template>

<script>
import Verte from 'verte';

export default {
  components: { Verte },
  data: () => ({
    colorVal: ''
  }),
  watch: {
    // whenever colorVal changes, this function will run
    colorVal(currentColor, previousColor) {
      // you can call changeColor function here.
      changeColor(currentColor);
    }
  },
  methods: {
   changeColor(id) {
    console.log(id)
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this is not suitable, since I need to change the color in the context of the table, passing the row id

Comment: the input event is suitable, but it fires several times for the verte component and for the vertepicker component

Comment: VertePicker support and fire change event, but how get this work..

Comment: I didn't find @change event in Verte picker doc.